# Apollo GraphQL: Pre-Fetching Data, but Query Hits Server Instead of Loading from Cache?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I've got this routine that's called when an element is hovered:

```
function prefetchDataOnHover(event){
    const messsageID = event.currentTarget.id;
    if ((Meteor.userId()) && (!prefetched_IMs)){
        client.query({
            query: INSTANTMESSAGES_QUERY,
            variables: {"fromID": Meteor.userId(), "toID": messsageID}
        });
        setPrefetched_IMs(true);
    }
}
```

It prefetches data used by my instant messages component. In that component I have a `<Query>` component:

```
<Query query={INSTANTMESSAGES_QUERY}
       variables={{"fromID": Meteor.userId(), "toID": remoteUserID}}> //<==confirmed same values as in pre-fetch
    {({subscribeToMore, loading, error, data, refetch}) => {
        if (loading) {
            [.....]
```

I've confirmed that the variables sent to INSTANTMESSAGES_QUERY are the same in both places. I would expect that the  component would retrieve the data from the cache. But instead, my server resolver runs and retrieves the data.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's just because I'm using `refetch` in the pre-loaded component.